# Impact of Fiori Apps on Server

Tags: sap-fiori

We are following Embedded Architecture for our S4HANA 1610 system.

Please let me know what will be the impact on Server if we implement 200+ Standard Fiori Apps in our System ?

Regards,

Sayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say “server”, are you referring to the ABAP backend, consisting of one or more SAP application servers and usually one database server?
In this case, you might get a very first impression using transaction `ST03`.
Here, you get a detailed analysis of resource consumption on the SAP application server.
You also get information about database access times, as seen from the application server.
This can give you a good hint about resource consumption on the database server.

Usually, the ABAP backend is accessed from Fiori via OData calls.
Not every user interaction causes an OData call, some interactions are handled locally at the frontend.

In general, implemented apps only require some space on the hard disk, as long as nobody is using them.
So the important questions for defining the expected workload are:

- How many users are working with these apps in which frequency  (Avg.
  thinktime)?
- How many OData calls are sent from these apps to the backend and how
  many dialog steps are handled by the frontend itself?
- How expensive are these OData calls  (see ST03)?

Every app reflects one or more typical business processes, which need to be defined.

Your specific Customizing also plays an important role, because it controls different internal functionality.

It’s also mandatory, to optimize database access, because in productive use, tables might get bigger in size, which might slow down database access over time.

Usually, this kind of sizing is done by SAP Hardware and Technology partners.